# Как получить название антивируса в переменную C#

Tags: c#

Как получить название антивируса в переменную на языке C#

Comment: Откуда получить?

Comment: Я не думаю, что это можно как то получить. Если только создать базу процессов, которые отвечают за антивирус и сканировать процессы. Если процесс найден в базе, то прочитать его имя и вывести.

Comment: Можно сделать через класс WMI, насколько я знаю, только вот как?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если пользоваться WMI, то можно сделать так:

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\SecurityCenter2",
                                            "SELECT * FROM AntiVirusProduct");

// это цикл по найденным антивирусам
foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
{
    string displayName = (string)queryObj["displayName"]; // имя
    Console.WriteLine($"Antivirus: {displayName}");

    uint productState = (uint)queryObj["productState"];
    uint secutityProvider = (productState & 0xff0000) >> 16; // что умеет

    Console.Write("Security provider:");
    if ((secutityProvider & 1) != 0) Console.Write(" firewall");
    if ((secutityProvider & 2) != 0) Console.Write(" autoupdate settings");
    if ((secutityProvider & 4) != 0) Console.Write(" antivirus");
    if ((secutityProvider & 8) != 0) Console.Write(" antispyware");
    if ((secutityProvider & 16) != 0) Console.Write(" internet settings");
    if ((secutityProvider & 32) != 0) Console.Write(" user account control");
    if ((secutityProvider & 64) != 0) Console.Write(" service");
    Console.WriteLine();

    uint realtimeStatus = (productState & 0xff00) >> 8; // realtime-защита
    Console.Write("Realtime status: ");
    switch (realtimeStatus)
    {
    case 0x00:
        Console.WriteLine("off"); break;
    case 0x01:
        Console.WriteLine("expired"); break;
    case 0x10:
        Console.WriteLine("on"); break;
    case 0x11:
        Console.WriteLine("snoozed"); break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("unknown"); break;
    }

    uint signatureStatus = (productState & 0xff); // состояние сигнатур
    Console.Write("Signature status: ");
    switch (signatureStatus)
    {
    case 0x00:
        Console.WriteLine("up to date"); break;
    case 0x10:
        Console.WriteLine("oout of date"); break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("unknown"); break;
    }
}
```

Источник: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-the-status-of-4b748f25

Если вам нужно только имя, и вы уверены, что антивирус на системе ровно один, можно упростить до

```
string name = (string)
    (new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\SecurityCenter2", "SELECT * FROM AntiVirusProduct")
            .Get().Cast<ManagementObject>().Single()["displayName"]);
```